# Should I use "besides" or "aside from" in the following case?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> **Speaker A:** So what's your plan for later?
>
> **Speaker B:** *Besides/aside from* continuing to wear this chicken costume? Nothing much.

What's the correct choice in this case. And why?

(Or maybe I should use apart?)

Comment: I asked a couple of people who teach writing. They say "besides" in conversation but would write "Aside from" in anything even slightly formal :)

Comment: I would use "other than".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "apart from", either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [the usage note of besides](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/besides)

For the meanings "in addition to" and "except for" besides should be used:

> Besides replacing the back stairs, she fixed the broken banister.

So your example should be written as follows:

> Besides continuing to wear this chicken costume? Nothing much.

EDIT:

As for the **aside from** and **apart from**, they both are equally correct, so you can use them all interchangeable.

Good read [here](http://writeworld.org/post/46417746656/besides-vs-aside-from) and [here](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/usage/besides.htm).

Comment: "Besides" is correct, but "Aside from" and "Apart from" are also both equally correct. I think this answer may be misleading to learners if you don't mention the other two options at all. :)

Comment: @Keiki, thanks a lot for the correction! I just missed it!:)

Comment: Are “aside from” and “besides” exchangeable in this case?

Comment: Let set_A (mathematically)  denote the plan, is "aside from" here indicating that the option "continuing to wear this chicken costume" **belongs to** the set_A?

Answer (score 2):

It's besides. There is lots of correct words to put there. But the best one in my opinion is besides.

Let's look what else could we put there:

**other than:** Other than continuing to wear this chicken costume? Nothing much.
**apart from:** Apart from continuing to wear this chicken costume? Nothing much.
**in addition to:** In addition to continuing to wear this chicken costume? Nothing much.

Meanings of the two words:

**beside:**
1. at the side of; next to.
2. in addition to; apart from.

**aside:**
1. to one side; out of the way.

As you see the second meaning of "beside" fits perfectly to the sentence.

Comment: Are “aside from” and “besides” exchangeable in this case?

Comment: Let set_A (mathematically)  denote the plan, is "aside from" here indicating that the option "continuing to wear this chicken costume" **belongs to** the set_A?